# Ubuntu 21.10 changes resolution, now screen unreadable

Tags: display, display-resolution

sorry for the poor quality question. Forced to type from mobile.

I am working on ubuntu for 2 week, without any problem. I have lenovo ryzen 7 laptop. Connected a displaylink usb c docking. Managed to get that to work using wayland.

Today, I worked on my laptop, disconnected from docking so on laptop screen. Some app was not scaling properly, so i changes the resolution from 3840x2160 to 1980x1020, and switched from 200% scaling to 100% scaling.

The screen looked horrible, pixelated, like the signal is completely wrong. I accidentally clicked on accept........

So with some care, i can select the previous working option (or any other, tried them all, with and without scaling). Whatever I do, the signal remains horrible.

What have I done? I don't want to completely reinstall ubuntu, i finally got everything to work... :(

Hope somebody has some tips here.

Comment: Ah... the refresh rate changed to some slightly off value. from 60 to 59.something. Putting it back to 60 solved my problem. Still it's a bit flickering on some parts of the screen, but at least I can see the contents again

Comment: Could you please move your comment into an answer and pick it as the right answer?

Comment: OK, will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resfresh rate was changed to 59.something. Changing it back to 60 solved my problem.

Comment: In the display settings...